# GH Pages Deploy Blank Page React

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I'm stuck on deploying my react app. It doesn't seem to create any errors but the page is blank. The app renders in local host.

Here is the repository: https://taylorepskamp.github.io/portfolio/

This is the top of my package.json file

```
  "name": "portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://taylorepskamp.github.io/portfolio/",
```

Here is my index.js file

```
class Root extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
                    <DesignerPortfolio/>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Root/>, document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorker.register();
```

I've looked at the console for any errors or reason for why the page is blank, I've tried deploying a very simple version of the app, I've repeated the initialization/deploy steps with a new repository, I've deleted the browser router portion of the index.js...Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: *"It doesn't seem to create any errors"* - `Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function`

Comment: Ok thanks I'll take a look at this one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You deleted a lot of necessary files for your React program. I suggest you create a new React App and copy and paste some of the code(Be careful with this because you don't want to copy the errors).

I had a similar problem until I watched this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wDzEjXbblM).

1) Change your `"homepage": "https://taylorepskamp.github.io/{Name of your project}/"`.

2) And change my the import of route component( BrowserRouter as Router to HashRouter as Router) in the index.js file.

3) Then re-deploy